# Android: Inherited View Scale

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Simple question: I have a RelativeLayout with several child objects, one of which is another Layout with several children of its own. The RelativeLayout is scalable by user choice, which also scales its children. I need to get one of the child objects' scale factors, but it always returns 1.0 even if the parent (or grandparent) is scaled. So I need a way to find out the *displayed* scale of an object, as opposed to its *set* scale. Any way to do this without manually checking through the list of parent objects and their scales? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other than trying with `((RelativeLayout) textView.getParent()).getScaleX()`, I don't think you have any other choice

Comment: @AjilO. I thought that might be the case... I suppose I'll have to see if I can work out a way to get total scale by recursively checking parent scale and calculate it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out. Here's how I did it.

```
public static float[] getInheritedScale(@NonNull View v)
{
    if(v.getParent() == null || !(v.getParent() instanceof View)){
        return new float[]{v.getScaleX(), v.getScaleY()};
    }

    float[] coords = new float[2];

    coords[0] = v.getScaleX();
    coords[1] = v.getScaleY();

    // Iterate through the View's family tree, getting each parent View's scale and calculating
    // it into the total scale factor.
    boolean done = false;
    View current = (View)v.getParent();
    while(!done)
    {
        coords[0] = coords[0] * current.getScaleX();
        coords[1] = coords[1] * current.getScaleY();

        // Check that we have not reached the top of the tree. If we have, set the done flag.
        if(current.getParent() != null && current.getParent() instanceof View){
            current = (View)current.getParent();
        }else{
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return coords;
}
```

This has worked in every case that I have tried it in. It returns the displayed (or apparent) scales (X/Y) of the view passed to it.